# What is the difference between []int and int[]

Tags: java, c++, arrays

When I want to implement a function in C++ , if it matters to receive the int array in the following cases?

```
void fn1(int []a) {
  a[0] = 1;
}

void fn2(int a[]) {
  a[0] = 1;
}
```

Comment: C++ and Java are two different languages. Which one are you actually interested in?

Comment: Yes it matters. The syntax for arrays in Java & C++ are different.

Comment: Again. [tag:c++] or [tag:java]?

Comment: Java would prefer former (atleast stylistically), c++ latter, but it is merely for appearance in c++ anyway

Comment: I don't see a `[] int` anywhere except in the title of this question...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Java, there is no semantic difference.

In C++, the first syntax is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the question is not clear.. Whether to receive the int array or not, it depends on the logics of your method. In Java it is better to write a[], but you can write either way.

Also, look over here - [pass array to method Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610757/pass-array-to-method-java)

Answer (score 2):

In Java,the declaration is same...
but in C++,the `fn1()` declaration need to be different