# Calling a method with an array as a parameter?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

While I understand how to call a method that uses varargs:

```
class TestClass {
    int a = 0;

    void applyValues(int...decrement) {
        for (int item : decrement) {
            a = a - item;
        }
    }
}
```

And then in main, assuming of course the object is created.

```
myobj.applyValues(1,2,3,4,5);
```

I do not understand how can I call a method that uses an array instead of varargs:

```
class TestClass {
    int a = 0;

    void applyValues(int[] decrement) {
        decrement[0] = 1000;
        decrement[1] = 2000;
        for (int item : decrement) {
            a = a - item;
        }
    }
}
```

And what should I call in main?

Comment: `myobj.applyValues(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5});`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610757/pass-array-to-method-java

Comment: Alright, that solved it, thanks!

Comment: The dupe should answer your question; you just pass it an `int[]`, there are no hoops to jump through. So pick your favorite way to create an `int[]` and pass it along like any other variable.