# How to input arrays into a method

Tags: java, arrays

So in a class called **Test2** there's a method that is

```
public static int[] number(int[] numbers) {
    System.out.println(numbers);
    return numbers;
{
```

And then in **Main**

```
Test2.number(?)
```

What do I write in the "?" so I can list some numbers and print them?

Comment: create a array and pass it and you can simply do this `Test2.number(new int[] {1, 2, 3})`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pass array to method Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610757/pass-array-to-method-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no but you can print integer arrays,

```java
int[] numArray = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
 Test2.number(numArray);
```

if you want to insert numbers instead of arrays change:

```java
public static int[] numbers (int[] numbers){
}
```

to

```java
public static int numbers (int numbers){

}
```

if you have any further problems please reply to this answer

Answer (score 1):

You just have to create an array. Please have a look for how to work with Java arrays in any search engine.

```
Test2.number(new int[]{1, 2, 3});
```

You could also change the signature of `number()` to take varargs to use just some numbers as parameter.

public static int[] numberVarargs(int...numbers)

Use it with:

```
Test2.number(1, 2, 3);
Test2.number(new int[]{1, 2, 3}); // using an array is still valid
```